# TSQL Materiaized/Indexed View Cluster index with subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, materialized-view

I have two tables: `Listings` and `Media` and `Media` is a child of `Listings`.  I am trying to create a indexed view that will include the first record from `Media`.  I would also like to index my view so that this view is as performance as possible.

View

```
ALTER VIEW GridListings
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 

SELECT l.ListingId, l.Title,
    (SELECT TOP 1 ThumbnailUrl 
        FROM [dbo].Media 
        WHERE ListingId = l.ListingId) as Thumbnail 
FROM [dbo].Listings l
```

Index

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20200528-150854] ON [dbo].[GridListings]
(
    [listingid] ASC
)
```

Error

> Cannot create index on view "dbo.GridListings"
>   because it contains one or more subqueries. Consider changing the view
>   to use only joins instead of subqueries. Alternatively, consider not
>   indexing this view.

The view I am going to create will include a lot of fields from `Listings` table, including a spatial field that I will need to filter on.

I have used the above approach to flatten both of my tables into a single list so that its fast to query and filter on which includes the thumbnail from `Media`.

Am I using the correct approach or is there a better/more performant way of doing it instead of indexed views

I am using SQL Server 2017

Here is the plan without any indexes on the view
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkdOyq6iL

Comment: I guess I was trying to "fix" the issue with indexed views but ultimately i just want to be able to have a list of my items that include one field from the child table  so if the query i posted above is the best way to go without the indexed view than I shall just do that

Comment: Use of TOP 1 without an order by clause does not meet the requirement "first record from Media". That will get you 1 undefined row from all those that match - not "first".

Comment: I added OrderBy MediaId and it went from 0 seconds to over 40 seconds (35k records in listings, 250k listings in media), there is an index on the PK of MediaId, fyi added a non-cluster index to Media on ListingId fixed the speed issue of orderby